# Acceder desde otra maquina por IP a proyecto, no muestra datos de select

Tags: mysql, formularios, apache, select, xampp

Necesito saber como solucionar o porque sucede lo siguiente...

Necesito hacer pruebas desde una laptop accediendo por `IP` a la maquina donde esta todo el proyecto, estando allí, se visualiza todo, los botones functions y demás, pero al abrir los formularios para algún registro o update, los select no cargan las información solo están en blanco y no puedo avanzar así, los select se cargan con información de la `BD` no son estáticos.

Las dos maquinas están en la misma red.

En la maquina donde esta el proyecto están activados los servicios de `apache` y `mysql` de `XAMPP` ademas que la `BD` esta en `MARIADB` de la misma.

Haciendo pruebas, si pongo datos estáticos en el `html`, de esta manera si aparece en la interfaz de la laptop. Pero es incorrecto.

Como puedo solucionar esto y que carguen los datos?

Comment: A que te refieres "A como esta hecho"? A que lenguajes de utilice? el proyecto esta hecho obviamente con html, php para apis, JS para functions, utilice bootstrap, jquery.....

Comment: Me refiero a que no sabemos cómo están cargándose los datos, construyéndose los selects. En su estado actual, la pregunta es vaga y difícil de responder siguiendo los lineamientos del sitio. Puedes mostrar cómo se cargan esos datos en el proyecto para ver por qué la IP desde la que se accede afecta el resultado

Comment: Actualizare la pregunta añadiendo código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he solucionado mi problema, en los `JS` para mandar a llamar una `api`, tenia la dirección de carpeta..

```
x.open('GET', 'http://localhost/WareHouse/apis/xxxx.php?getAll=true', true);
```

Solamente cambie el localhost por la ip de la maquina, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
x.open('GET', 'http://192.168.0.1/WareHouse/apis/xxxx.php?getAll=true', true);
```

De esta manera en la maquina donde intento acceder ya cargan los `combobox`.